# Select a field from two tables in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a Sqlite Database with 2 tables, Table1 and Table2, both have a field "name", my goal is to display names that is similar to each table in a listview

```
Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.name = table2.name where table2.name LIKE '%" + txtSearch + "%'", null);
```

it only display the result in table2 :( please help

Comment: Which columns does the listview show? Which should it show?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the problem comes from your join statement. You can try as below:

```
select t1.* from table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 ON t1.name = table2.name where table2.name LIKE '%" + txtSearch + "%'"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response :) however, my listview is still blank after i typed "john" in my searchTxt

Comment: @PeacegleMayor You should post the code which is used to read Table 1 from cursor. Maybe you can log the count of `cursor` to understand more.